# What's the envelope curve appear in this graph?

Tags: functions, graphing-functions

I graphed the curve defined by

$$y=3|e^{-(x/2-1/3)^2+ibx}+e^{-(x/2+1/3)^2-ibx}|$$

where $b=1000$. The graph is here:

https://dl.dropbox.com/u/9034084/screenshots/interference.png

Clearly when b goes to infinity one can talk about the envelope of this family. So my question is, what are the envelope curves (I'm curious on both upper bound and lower bound) ?

Comment: You need to have a negative sign infront of the second $b$.

Comment: fixed. thanks a lot.

Comment: How about $3\Big\lvert e^{-(x/2-1/3)^2}\pm e^{-(x/2+1/3)^2}\Big\rvert$?

Comment: @RahulNarain You are exactly right. (I only checked the graph. That is apparently the max possible amplitude.)

Comment: @RahulNarain Do you know what the smoothing of the curve is, I mean the function whose value at $x$ is the average of the current function on $[x-c, x+c]$, and $c\ll b$. I'm trying to get a good picture of interference.

Comment: I assume you mean $b^{-1} \ll c \ll 1$. I don't know the arithmetic average, but the root-mean-square value of $\lvert\alpha e^{ibx}+\beta e^{-ibx}\rvert$ is just $\sqrt{\alpha^2+\beta^2}$, so...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The graph will lie between the following curves
$$3 \left( e^{-(x/2-1/3)^2}+e^{-(x/2+1/3)^2} \right)$$
and
$$3 \left \vert e^{-(x/2-1/3)^2}-e^{-(x/2+1/3)^2} \right \vert$$
since $$\vert \vert c \vert - \vert d \vert \vert \leq \left \vert c e^{ibx} + d e^{-ibx} \right \vert \leq \vert c \vert + \vert d \vert$$

Comment: I'm willing to accept this. But you should give Rahul Narain some credit in your answer.

Comment: @hyh: There's no need for that. Marvis arrived at the solution independently and has also given the *reason* why these bounds work.

Comment: @RahulNarain OK then. The reason is obvious once someone pointed that out.

Answer (score 0):

We change some constants to make this easier to work with...
$$\begin{eqnarray*}y &=& \left|e^{-(x-1)^2+ibx}+e^{-(x+1)^2-ibx} \right| \\
&=& \left|e^{-(x-1)^2}(\cos(bx)+i\sin(bx))+e^{-(x+1)^2}(\cos(bx)-i\sin(bx)) \right| \\
&=& \left|\left(e^{-(x-1)^2}+e^{-(x+1)^2}\right)\cos(bx) + i\left(e^{-(x-1)^2}-e^{-(x+1)^2}\right)\sin(bx) \right| \\
&=& \sqrt{\cos^2(bx)\left(e^{-(x-1)^2}+e^{-(x+1)^2}\right)^2 + \sin^2(bx)\left(e^{-(x-1)^2}-e^{-(x+1)^2}\right)^2} \\
&=&\sqrt{\left(\cos^2(bx)+\sin^2(bx)\right)\left(e^{-2(x-1)^2}+e^{-2(x+1)^2}\right) + 2\left(\cos^2(bx)-\sin^2(bx)\right)\left(e^{-(x-1)^2-(x+1)^2}\right)} \\
&=& \sqrt{e^{-2(x-1)^2}+e^{-2(x+1)^2}+2\cos(2bx)e^{-2(x^2+1)}}\end{eqnarray*}$$

The last term is the oscillatory term, with $\cos(bx)$ ranging between $-1$ and $1$. Hence, the envelopes are $\sqrt{e^{-2(x-1)^2} + e^{-2(x+1)^2} \pm 2e^{-2(x^2+1)}}$.